# Are Microsoft Entity Framework and ADO.NET Entity Framework (.edmx) the same?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net

This might be a stupid question. I have no idea about MS Entity Framework (I think I need to download something from Microsoft website like logging framework).

I have recently came across an `.edmx` file in Visual Studio and got to know little bit about it.

I am still confused if MS Entity Framework and this .edmx are same.

I believe these two are same. Please put some light on this.

Comment: Phew - read this might clear the confusion - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx , yes as far as I know its same thing, hope it helps, cheers

Comment: You may be confusing Entity Framework with Enterprise Library.

Comment: @John - you are right... i was confused in btwn these two. I though Entity Framework is like Enterprise Library... thanks for you help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EDMX file is an XML document used  by the Entity Framework. So, yes, EDMX and Entity Framework are both about the same thing.

Entity Framework is essentially and object/relational mapper.

This is a great place to get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef